# Redirect Old .php URLs to New Wordpress Page

Tags: theme-development, redirect

I have an old website that I'm revamping with a custom new Wordpress theme. The old site had a custom (non-WP based) downloads archive that mapped URLs like this:

`/downloads/view.php?id=2`

The ID maps to a download item in a separate MySQL database.

I'd like to move everything over to Wordpress in this refresh and I'm going to be using a custom post type to handle the downloads section, with a custom field that maps the "old ID" to the new post. This isn't difficult and I know how to do this, but the issue becomes remapping the old URLs to the new locations.

The issue I see is that the older URLs are all PHP files (have an extension of `.php`). How would I go about create a plugin or Wordpress function in my theme's functions.php file to redirect these old URLs to a new URL. Essentially, I just need to have a Wordpress function redirect from `/downloads/view.php?id=2` to `/downloads/2/`, or another more optimized URL (`/downloads/title-of-archive`).

How would I go about handling pages with a URL of "`/downloads/view.php`" and "`/downloads/download.php`" and performing the redirect?

I know I can use the `.htaccess` file, but I'd prefer to do this directly in a Wordpress plugin if possible for portability...

Comment: Is your web server an Apache? If so, I would handle that in the Apache config or .htaccess file.

Comment: This seems more like a question for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), as it deals more with .htaccess then WordPress.

Comment: I'd prefer to do this in a Wordpress plugin to avoid having to make this modification to servers I move to in the future or after reinstalling Wordpress...

Comment: @AndrewM I added a solution which actually puts in the URL for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue by hooking onto the "`template_redirect`" action. After that, I check if the page `is_404()` and then check if the URL matches my pattern. I set the appropriate header (`301` versus the `404` that normally would be triggered) and perform my redirect. My code is below.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'handle_download_urls');

function handle_download_urls(){
    if(is_404()){
        if(preg_match('/\/downloads\/(?:view\.php|download\.php)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && isset($_GET['id'])){
            // Do lookup of post based on custom metadata field
            // Redirect and change header
            status_header(301);
            header('Location: [URL]');
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with rewrites, but honestly, it's not a rewrite what you want. A rewrite would just have the old url to act like the new url instead of redirecting it to the new location. Please not that you still need to make sure `/downloads/id/` is handled by your WordPress. Now there you could use rewrite.

Add the following code to your templates `function.php`:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'get_current_url' ) ) {
    /**
     * Gets the current displayed url
     * @returns the url
     */
    function get_current_url( ) {
        $url  = isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        $url .= ( strlen( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
        $url .= ( strval( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) != '80' ) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] : '';
        $url .= $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
        return $url;    
    }
}

/**
 * Permanently redirects old /downloads/view.php?id=X and /downloads/download.php?id=X
 * to /downloads/X/. 
 */
function permanent_301_redirect_downloads() {  

    $matches = array();
    $url = get_current_url();

    // $matches[1] has view or download, and $matches[2] the id
    if ( preg_match( '/downloads\/(view|download)\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\/?$/', $url, $matches ) ) :
        // Fetch the title of the archive. Are these posts? I wouldn't know
        $archive = $matches[2];
        wp_redirect( trailingslashit( home_url('') . '/downloads/' . $archive ) , 301 );  
        exit;
    endif;

}  
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'permanent_301_redirect_downloads' );
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect `/downloads/view.php?id={some-name}` to `/downloads/{some-name}/`, add the following to your .htaccess file, before the default WordPress rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^downloads/view.php?id=(.+) downloads/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It will also let search engines know that your downloads have moved, and to update their index.

Comment: Is there a way to do this directly from Wordpress, without modifying the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: There is the [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API), but that's more for making ugly URLs (with query args, such as `downloads/view.php?id=2`) look pretty (like `/downloads/2/`), not the other way around. 

For more info on the Rewrite API, check out the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) or this [WPSE answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3258934/1042798).

Comment: @shea does this go into the root `.htaccess`, and will this cover subfolders in the domain?

Answer (score -1):

Old Custom Php URLS Redirect to Home or other pages .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^clients.php https://mybtechnology.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

This will work 100%
```

Comment: The OP: "I know I can use the .htaccess file, but I'd prefer to do this directly in a Wordpress plugin if possible for portability."

Comment: yes you can use redirection plugin in wordpress, it will work there.